# SQL Group by day from timestamp with two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with timestamp columns.

Table #1 contains clicks, timestamp and Table #2 contains userid, timestamp. I want the counts of clicks and users by date. for example

```
Date        clicks_count  users_count

2015-07-24    10            15
2015-07-24    04            06
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select date(timestamp), 
       sum(is_click) as clicks,
       sum(is_click = 0) as user_count
from
(
  select timestamp, 1 as is_click from table1
  union all 
  select timestamp, 0 from table2
) tmp
group by date(timestamp)
```

You can select the `timestamp`s from both tables together and add a calculated column that indicates from which table the timestamp came from.

Then you take that subquery result and group by by the date and count the users and clicks.

`sum(is_click = 0)` counts how many time the timestamp came from the users table.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine but i am not able understand this code. Can you please explain me if possible?

Comment: what if we have one more column on the first table and we want that count also? How we can get it?

Comment: Please be more specific. If you cant find a suitable answer to your question  then add a new one and explain in detail what you have and what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think these SQL useful to you.

```
select a.date1,clicks_count,users_count  from 
(select date(Table1.timestamp)as date1, count(clicks) as clicks_count
from Table1 
group by date(Table1.timestamp)) as a
join
(
select date(Table2.timestamp) date2, count(userid) as users_count
from Table2 
group by date(Table2.timestamp)) b on a.date1 = b.date2
```

Thank you.

Comment: But what if there is a date not present in table1 which is in table2? The join would leave that out. You would need a full outer join which MySQL does not support